# Avoiding require cycle (refresh auth token at redux middleware)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, jwt

Would be glad to get an idea of how to destruct my code for avoiding a require cycle (I'm not encountering any bug or so, just want to make my code the best possible, w/t memory leaking, encounter unset vars or damage performance/readability)

My hierarchy looks like so:

```
 services
 -- api.ts
 -- userService.ts
 store
 -- actions
 ---- auth.ts
 -- index.tsx
 -- jwt.ts
```

At `store/index.tsx` I'm importing `store/jwt.ts` for -

```
const store = createStore(reducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, jwt)))
```

While at `store/jwt.ts` I'm importing `actions/auth.ts` for -

```
import { refreshToken as refreshTokenFunc } from './actions/auth'

const jwt: Middleware = ({ dispatch, getState }: { dispatch; getState: () => IRootState }) => {
    return (next) => (action) => {
        const nextAction = () => next(action)
            if (should refresh token) {
                return !getState().auth.refreshTokenPromise
                    ? refreshTokenFunc(dispatch).then(nextAction)
                    : getState().auth.refreshTokenPromise.then(nextAction)
            }
        return nextAction()
    }
}
```

(While I'm having `refreshTokenPromise` as a redux variable for avoiding calling refresh token endpoint a few times in a row but waiting for the same call to end.)

`refreshTokenFunc` from `actions/auth.ts` uses `userService.refreshToken` (and imports `userService...`)

```
export async function refreshToken(dispatch) {
    const handleErr = () => Promise.reject(dispatch(logout()))
    
    const refreshTokenPromise = userService
        .refreshToken(... some params)
        .then(({ status, ...rest }) => {
            status
                ? dispatch(...)
                : handleErr()
        })
        .catch(handleErr)
    await dispatch({
        type: AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        refreshTokenPromise
    })
    return refreshTokenPromise
}
```

`services/userService.ts` imports main `services/api.ts` service

```
import API from './api'

refreshToken: (params) =>
        API.post(EEndPoints.REFRESH_TOKEN, ...params)
```

and `services/api.ts` imports `store/index.tsx` for common `getState` either `dispatch` common things as

```
store.dispatch({ type: GENERAL_TOGGLE_NO_INTERNET })
store.dispatch({ type: AUTH_LOGOUT }) // in case token sent returned as invalid by API...)
```

to sum up -

**services/userService.ts** ->
services/api.ts ->
store/index.tsx ->
store/jwt.ts ->
store/actions/auth.ts ->
**services/userService.ts**

I'm sure I'm not the first one using middleware for refreshing tokens, having this kind of hierarchy, or using a main `api` service with common `dispatch` or `getState`, so maybe someone found a way around this loop. Any time I try to change some of the imports I still have this loop just from a different file to a different file (for example from `store/actions/auth.ts` to itself back)

I tried to keep the code as minimal as possible, in case it's not clear enough please comment.

Any idea/thought will be very appreciated! :)

Comment: You could create something like `services/common/refreshToken` and have `userService` and `actions/auth` import from that. What else is `userService` responsible for besides refreshing the token?

Comment: In general the way to solve cycles is to introduce another module.

Comment: @morganney it won't change the fact that it gonna be require cycle, just I'll have another file in the process

Comment: What would the cycle be if you introduced another module? `store/actions/auth` and `services/userService` both importing from the new module should not create another cycle unless there is more imports not shown.

Comment: maybe I don't fully understand what you mean, but how it will help? `userService` will need main `api`, and `actions/auth` will need `userService`. even if I'll create a new service it will need to use `api`, and the refresh function will still be in need for it service

Comment: You extract the common functionality between `userService` and `actions/auth` into a third module. Think about it.

Comment: even if I'll import main `api` directly in `actions/auth` (that it totally equal to creating new file with the function and service call) I'll have the require cycle, just with one file less